# Web application cannot talk to web service when run on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis

I am calling a web service (for sms sending) in my asp.net web application. When my web application is on Developer Server, the web service is called and everything is fine, the expected results are returned. However, when the application is run on IIS, I cannot call the web service and I get this `WebException`:

"Unable to connect to the remote server"

And in details, `InnerException`, the message is "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it SomeIP:SomePort" where *SomeIP* is the web service IP address and *SomePort* is 80

(I was suspecting the problem is the port 80, since pinging *SomeIP* returns a response but Telnet on *SomeIP SomePort* fails. But I'm not sure if this is really the problem, I mean, how could the application set a different port when run on IIS!)

I really appreciate any help or ideas!

Comment: It could be the Firewall, are the production and development server in the same network?

Comment: It's not connecting to your service on port 80 because that is the port that IIS is already using.

Comment: @therealtbs: I have turned windows firewall off. Not sure if there is something else preventing the web service call :(

Comment: @PhoenixReborn: But isn't port 80 on the target machine where the sms web service is located?? What does it have to do with my machine's port 80?? (Sorry I'm not that good with network concepts)

Comment: No, port 80 is what IIS is using to communicate with everyone else. That is the default port in use by a web server.

Comment: Are the web service and your application on the same machine?

Comment: Try to execute `netstat -a` command and check if there is a TCP port 80 in LISTENING state, just to make sure that your IIS is running.

Comment: @therealtbs: No, the web service is provided by some third party company, and my application can talk to it perfectly fine when I run my app on Developer Server in .NET

Comment: @kkokosa: Yep. there is one.

Comment: Are your development server and your iis server in the same network? I assume the IIS server is hosted by a third party. If so, please check with your hoster if they block port 80 outgoing.

Comment: @therealtbs, Yep, on the same network (and on the same machine)

Comment: Please add some code to your original question. Also which version of Visual Studio do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue wherein the unit test was successfully able to call the external web service, while the asp.net mvc application I was working on was unable to.

I had to a web.config entry to make it work. I am sharing the config entry, which I think, could help people with a similar issue. By the way, this section goes directly under the root  element within web.config file. Replace proxy server name and port as applicable in your context.

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy proxyaddress="http://<proxy server name>:<port>" />
    </defaultProxy>
    <!--<defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy usesystemdefault="True" bypassonlocal="True" />
    </defaultProxy>-->
</system.net>
```